# SCALA TERADATA SQL Exception

Tags: scala, teradata

I am new to teradata and also scala. I am executing a query in scala which is throwing SQL Exception but the same query is running fine in Teradata studio.

Below is the query:

```
 SELECT COUNT(loan_no)
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
FROM testdb.loan
WHERE field1 < DATE '2017-09-30'
GROUP BY field1
    ,field2
    ,field3
ORDER BY field1
```

Error received is:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20]
>   [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a
>   name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or
>   '(' between the 'FROM' keyword and the 'Select' keyword.

Scala code

```
val queryString = "SELECT COUNT(loan_no),field1,field2,field3 FROM testdb.loan WHERE field1 < DATE '2017-09-30' GROUP BY field1,field2,field3 ORDER BY field1"

val connString = 
"jdbc:teradata://test.udaystd.com/,TMODE=TERA,charset=UTF8, 
 user="+userid+", password="+passwd+", ,charset=UTF8"

val dbdriver = "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"

val jddf = sqlContext.load("jdbc",
  Map("url" -> connString,
   "dbtable" -> queryString,
   "driver" -> dbdriver))
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the Scala code that includes this query? Sounds like this might be an issue with the way you create the string literal.

Comment: can you try to run it w/out the where clause?

Comment: i tried that too and result is same error.  The only way it works is when i have it like ( (select * from testdb.loan) as loandata)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix by using the below code

```
val queryString = " (SELECT COUNT(loan_no) as loancnt 
,field1,field2,field3 FROM testdb.loan WHERE field1 < DATE '2017-09-30' 
GROUP BY field1,field2,field3) as LOANDATA"
```

Also, i could not use order by. So i ordered it after getting it in dataframe.

```
val orderedDF = df.orderBy($"field1".desc)
```

Comment: Seems like scala prefixes `SELECT * FROM `, which also explains the inability to add `ORDER BY` (it's not allowed in Derived Table). I never worked with Scala, but there should be some setting to change this.

Comment: you are right about select * from getting prefixed. If i need it otherwise, i have to use result set and convert that to df

Comment: You can add the order by in the query, I guess the problem was that you didn't enclose the query in two parenthesis "( ... ) qry".